# Oracle and SQL Server database with same schema in single Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

I have a task in my existing application that we have 2 different databases, one in SQL Server and another in Oracle, but both schemas are the same.

Currently we have an ASP.NET MVC application using Entity Framework and SQL Server. Can I use the same entity model against the Oracle database, without code change? Because some of the datatypes in Oracle and SQL Server are quite different, so common entity model `.edmx` is not working and code also throws error. Is there any way to achieve this?

Please give me a hint so I can go further.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that one solution is to use the same csdl amd msl part of the edmx file that you have already created through your sql server connection and have different ssdl for every database type.

If you don't know where they are located in your project or how to access them just right click in the edmx file in you solution explorer and select open with and choose xml editor.
there you can see that each part has it's name in comment's section

[image]

Moreover there is a Microsoft tool EdmGen.exe that is part of .net framework(so do not have to download it ,you have it already)

Info about the tool:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896270(v=vs.110).aspx

Through this tool you can convert the ssdl file to an oracle equivalent .

Due to the fact that is something i am working too these period i dont have a full answer but that can give you a start